convert ensta API Post type to json in python?
I have used Ensta API to fetch data from instagram API -
from ensta import Guest

guest = Guest()

posts = guest.posts(username='kapilsharma', count=1)
for post in posts:
    print(post)
    print(type(post))

How can I convert below data to json.dumps in python?
Post(share_url='https://www.instagram.com/p/DANRCkyPxzG/', taken_at=1726982023, post_id='3462498632245124294', media_type=8, code='DANRCkyPxzG', caption_is_edited=False, original_media_has_visual_reply_media=False, like_and_view_counts_disabled=False, can_viewer_save=True, profile_grid_control_enabled=False, is_comments_gif_composer_enabled=True, comment_threading_enabled=True, comment_count=939, has_liked=False, user=PostUser(has_anonymous_profile_picture=False, fbid_v2='17841402440257086', transparency_product_enabled=False, is_favorite=False, is_unpublished=False, uid='2616689341', username='bombaytimes', full_name='Bombay Times', is_private=False, is_verified=True, profile_picture_id='3273345353686890427_2616689341', profile_picture_url='https://instagram.fbho4-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/416541756_1566820497488671_8579242971939705171_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=instagram.fbho4-3.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=HYnNyrRoiQUQ7kNvgFuXIaa&edm=ACWDqb8BAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYAenbV-2lYvd8Tnm1bkof_Usy6MjfCh1hSQhrnhWQi05A&oe=66F765BF&_nc_sid=ee9879', account_badges=[], feed_post_reshare_disabled=False, show_account_transparency_details=True, third_party_downloads_enabled=1, latest_reel_media=0), can_viewer_reshare=True, like_count=470912, top_likers=[], caption_text='‘I am more motivated to do good work so that they understand that they are proud of their papa’\n\nOn #DaughtersDay, comedian and actor @kapilsharma talks about how his daughter motivates him to be a better person every day\n\nTap the link in our stories to read \n.\n.\n.\n#daughtersday #kapilsharma #anayra #fatherdaughter #fatherdaughterlove #thekapilsharmashow', is_caption_covered=False, caption_created_at=1726982024, caption_share_enabled=False, caption_did_report_as_spam=False, is_paid_partnership=False, show_shop_entrypoint=False, deleted_reason=0, integrity_review_decision='pending', ig_media_sharing_disabled=False, has_shared_to_fb=3, is_unified_video=False, should_request_ads=False, is_visual_reply_commenter_notice_enabled=True, commerciality_status='not_commercial', explore_hide_comments=False, has_delayed_metadata=False, location_latitude=0, location_longitude=0)

<class 'ensta.containers.Post.Post'>

